# Socket.io in laravel 5 for chat

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, redis, socket.io

So i have a script using socket io, a node.js server and a redis queue for a live chat in laravel

I have a everything is working and the redis queue is accepting input, i can see it when i use 'redis-cli monitor', however the messages arent being outputted into the socket view

The socket.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('content')
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.3.4.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg10 col-lg-offset-2" >
            <div id="messages" ></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8890');
    socket.on('message', function (data) {
        $( "#messages" ).append( "<p>"+data+"</p>" );
    });
</script>


@endsection
```

socketController.php

```
<?php

namespace SocialNet\Http\Controllers;
use SocialNet\Http\Requests;
use SocialNet\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Request;
use LRedis;

class SocketController extends Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    public function index()
     {
        return view('socket');
    }
    public function writemessage()
    {
        return view('writemessage');
    }
    public function sendMessage(){
        $redis = LRedis::connection();
        $redis->publish('message', Request::input('message'));
        return redirect('writemessage');
    }
}
```

What am i missing here?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked in my browser console and found that it was a connection refused error. I then checked the client side connection to the socket.io and changed the connection to the IP of the VM that the node server was running on from http://localhost and it worked perfectly!